# Comparing Two Lines In Opened Files With For Loops

Tags: python, loops, file-handling, readlines

Okays guys this code works but not as i want it , If anyone could help I want it to take the first line in hash_replace and check through every single line in hash_found until it finds one , but this code just compares them side by side.If anyone could help i would be grateful.

```
with open('resolute','r') as renny:
    with open('ronny','r') as renna:
        for line,line2 in zip(renny,renna):
            lin = line.split()
            li = line2.split()
            hash_to_replace = lin[2]
            email = lin[0]
            hash_found = li[0]
            pass_found = li[2]
            if hash_to_replace == hash_found:
                print('Found')
            else:
                print('Nothing')
```

Comment: If you only want to read 1 line from one file, why are you reading from both in a loop?

Comment: @ScottHunter I would like to take the first line in 'hash_to_replace then loop through 'hash_found' then take the second line in 'hash_to-replace' then loop through 'hash_found' .I want this process to go on until it takes the last line and loops .Do you think you could help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 nested loops: for each `line`, loop over all of the `line2`s:

```
with open('resolute','r') as renny:
    for line in renny:
        with open('ronny','r') as renna:
            for line2 in renna:
```